# how to install HAL on Puppy Linux barebone 5.7.1

Tags: software-installation, adobe-flash, puppy-linux

On other linux distros I have to install `hal` for certain flash player videos to work. youtube works fine with the adobe flash.

Just can't find anything on installing `hal` in puppy linux.

Comment: HAL was deprecated, and what remained was merged with udev. Why do you want the old HAL package?

Comment: certain things with flash need it(at least in Ubuntu 13.10). Only works with firefox, chrome has this pepper thing that doesnt let Hal interact with chrome. its a DRM thing.

Comment: seems no one is going to help....